# VBA ListBox add item using worksheet variable

Tags: vba

I have an ActiveX ListBox called "Listbox1" in "Start" worksheet.
Why `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("START").ListBox1.AddItem ("a")` works and 
`shStart.ListBox1.AddItem ("b")` didn't.

I received this error: `Method or data member not found`

```
Dim tw As Workbook
Dim shStart As Worksheet
Set tw = ThisWorkbook
Set shStart = tw.Worksheets("START")

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("START").ListBox1.AddItem ("a")
shStart.ListBox1.AddItem ("b")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Worksheet` class is [non-extensible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28218373/11683). This means that if you declare a variable of the type `Worksheet`, you can only call methods and properties that are pre-declared with the `Worksheet` type. You cannot access any methods or properties that you defined on the sheet in addition to that.

Your options are:

- Declare the variable as the type of the exact sheet (using its [codename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481428/11683))

  ```
  Dim shStart as Sheet1
  ```
- Declare the variable as `Object`
- Keep using the `Worksheets("START")` syntax (it returns an `Object` too, which is why it also works).